# How to correct add link using append in js

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, append

How can i correct append a link when create div? A have a code like this to create a div.

```
$("#container").append('<div class="square" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href"'+ webAdress + '></div>')
```

And the result is:

```
<div class="square" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href" www.bbc.com=""></div>
```

The problem is i have a double quotes after webadress instead of one and equal sign which i didnt add.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a work around would be to use [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

So instead of your code it would be something like this.

```
$("#container").append(`<div class="square" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='${webAdress}'"></div>`)
```

Comment: Work great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with this :

```
$("#container").append('<div class="square" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="()=>{location.href=webAdress}"></div>');
```

Comment: This does not work. After creating there is ${webAdress} in html